# Cpython consists of C code or binary machine code

Tags: cpython

What is the meaning and the significance of Cpython is the implementation of python.

It is the interpreter, which used C language to create the Cpython program. It was than compiled to machine code, object code. When Cpython is executed, does it consist of actual C language code, it should be only machine code. Python code is converted to C code and again to bytecode?

Is it working backwards, the machine code, being the compiled output of C code used to create it, C code is mapped back to the python code? what is it telling you as a programmer, when it says the implementation of python is cpython programmed in C,
as with any program you create, you choose a language.

Comment: I find it hard to parse what your actual question is, but: CPython is the implementation of the Python interpreter, written in C. Like (almost) all C programs, this has been compiled into machine code by a C compiler to get a binary that runs on your machine. There any direct connection with machine code ends: CPython interprets Python code, no translation to machine code is happening. The machine code that is running consists of functions that together parse and execute Python code, but this is not specific to the Python code being run.

Comment: I have read somewhere, the machine code that is run is the last stage in the PVM, it is specific to each bytecode instruction.